# How do I transfer a boolean value from the main activity to a class?

Tags: java, android

so i am trying to transfer a `boolean` value "isclicked" from a button in the main activity to a Java class that would use that value (true) in an if statement , the debugger shows no errors but the app crashes on launch , here is a snippet of my code:

**Main.java**

```
if (isclicked) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AP.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("isclicked", "true");
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }else{
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AP.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("isclicked", "false");
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

**and AP.java**

```
Boolean value = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isclicked", false);
```

any other methods are welcomed.

Comment: The crash is unrelated.  This code is fine (if a bit wasteful-  you don't need an if, just putExtra("isclicked", isclicked) will work for both).  Also, using a constant for the name of the extra is a good idea to prevent typos.

Comment: Wouldn't `putExtra("isclicked", "true");` put a String, not a boolean?

Comment: And is `AP.java` an `Activity`? You just say it is a "Java class", so you can't just send an Intent to a normal Java class like that.

Comment: Try to add the flag for a new task:  `myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(myIntent);`

Comment: Exactly as @cricket stated, you're putting a String extra, not a boolean extra.  Either remove the double quotes around true and false, or do as Gabe suggested. remove the if/else and just give it the boolean value: `myIntent.putExtra("isclicked", isclicked;`

Comment: i simplified the code by removing the string and the else statement and replacing the string "false" with simply "isclicked" and now it runs without any trouble , thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify it a bit, like this and it will work:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AP.class);
myIntent.putExtra("isclicked", isclicked);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isclicked) {    
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AP.class);
    myIntent .putExtras("isclicked", true);
    startActivity(myIntent);    
}
```

Retrieve intent extra:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Boolean value = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isclicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Code

```
    if (isclicked) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AP.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("isclicked", "true");
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

// Change

```
    if (isclicked) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AP.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("isclicked", true);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Do not pass the boolean value in quotes. If you pass that in quotes, it will be passed as string. Just pass true and not "true".